# How to get particular date of last 2nd of March based on today (bash)

Tags: linux, bash, date

The requirement is to get last 2nd of March in CI process in any year, meaning:

Today is: **23 Feb 2024** - last 2nd of March will be 02/03/**2023**

Today is: **23 Mar 2024** - last 2nd of March will be 02/03/**2024** (current year)

How i can automate it in CI process (using `date` command)?

Comment: Start by googling and looking at the output of `man date`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Bash, if you have only POSIX or BSD `date` you can do:

```
#!/bin/bash

this_year=$(date "+%Y")
last_year=$(( this_year-1 ))  # bash only...
month=$(date "+%m")
day=$(date "+%d")

if [[ "${this_year}${month}${day}" > "${this_year}0302" ]]; then
    echo "${this_year}0302"
else
    echo "${last_year}0302"
fi
```

This works since the format of `YYYYMMDD` can correctly sort strings representing a date in lexicographical order corresponding to the actual date. This is codified by the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard.

Answer (score 1):

It's as simple as below:

```
samveen@zero2w:~ $ date -d 'march 2 last year'
Thu  2 Mar 00:00:00 IST 2023
```

Supply the output format parameter as required.

*Edit: As pointed out in the comments, this is only for GNU date (i.e. Linux and similar environments(i.e. Ubuntu WSL).*

*Edit 2: Seems to be fine for "January 2 last year", as below:*

```
samveen@X230:~$ date -d 'january 2 last year'
Monday 02 January 2023 12:00:00 AM IST
```

Comment: GNU date only...

Comment: This doesn't work after March 2. Test it with `date -d 'january 2 last year'` and you'll get the date of the last year, but not of the previous january 2.